# Сортировка данных массива в двусвязном списке

Tags: c#, массивы, сортировка, linked-list

По заданию лабораторной работы необходимо создать двусвязный список узлы которого содержат в себе массивы строкового типа с ячейками "ФИО, телефон, год рождения".

Необходимо реализовать вывод фамилий и телефонов  людей старше 25 лет и упорядочить их по возрасту.

Подскажите, как лучше реализовать такую сортировку. Я смог прописать вывод списка и добавление значений, но как сделать подобную сортировку не могу понять.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DoublyLinkedList<string[]> linkedList = new DoublyLinkedList<string[]>();

        linkedList.Add(new string[] { "Егоров Алексей Викторович", "89021562233", "2001" });
        linkedList.Add(new string[] { "Купышев Кирилл Алексеевич", "89443325532", "2003" });
        linkedList.Add(new string[] { "Хопкинс Лектор Ганнибалович", "89750521145", "1993" });
        linkedList.Add(new string[] { "Фишер Сэм Иванович", "89212342254", "1967" });
        linkedList.Add(new string[] { "Смирнов Егор Егорович", "89880624544", "1995" });

        linkedList.OutputList(linkedList, "Телефонная книга");
        
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}

public class DoublyNode<T>
    {
        public DoublyNode(T data)
        {
            Data = data;
        }
        public T Data { get; set; }
        public DoublyNode<T> Previous { get; set; }
        public DoublyNode<T> Next { get; set; }
    }
public class DoublyLinkedList<T> : IEnumerable<T>  // двусвязный список
{
    DoublyNode<T> head; // головной/первый элемент
    DoublyNode<T> tail; // последний/хвостовой элемент
    int count;  // количество элементов в списке

    public void OutputList(DoublyLinkedList<string[]> list, string label)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(label);
        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (string[] item in list)
            Console.WriteLine(item[0] + ", телефон: " + item[1] + "год рождения: " + item[2]);

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    // добавление элемента
    public void Add(T data)
    {
        DoublyNode<T> node = new DoublyNode<T>(data);

        if (head == null)
            head = node;
        else
        {
            tail.Next = node;
            node.Previous = tail;
        }
        tail = node;
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Лучше если бы заводили свой двусвязный список не на типе string[], а на нормальном классе, содержащем конкретные поля ФИО, телефон, год. Тогда бы было всё красиво и на примере с CityInfo отсюда: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.comparison-1 А так только внешняя функция сортировки, вызывающая функцию Swap(DoublyNode item1, DoublyNode item2) у DoublyLinkedList на основе примитивного сравнения: bool por(string[] first, string[] second) => int.Parse(first[2]) <= int.Parse(second[2]);

Comment: Спасибо за наводку!